# Desabitiar os options não selecionados de multiselect com jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```js
$('#columns-selected').change(function(){

    let menu = [];

    for (i=0; i < 5; i++){
        let opcao = $('#columns-selected option:selected')[i]; 
  
        if (opcao){
            menu.push($(opcao).val());
        };
    }

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: base_url+'fornecedor/menuPadrao/',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: { menu: menu },
      success: function(data)
       {
         if(!data.result == true){
           alert('Ocorreu um erro tente novamente!');
         }
       }
      
    });
})
```

1 - Hoje no select posso selecionar vários mas o mesmo só pega os 5 primeiros selecionados e enviar via ajax para o controller como mostra o código acima.

Duvida/Pergunta/Sugestão

Como faria para que quando o usuário selecionasse 5, além de envia os 5 via ajax, desabilita-se o resto dos options no select ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz o teste ai mano!
acredito que resolva seu problema.

```
$('#columns-selected').change(function(){

//FAZ A CONTAGEM DE OPÇÕES MARCADAS NO SELECT
var selectedOptions = $("#columns-selected :selected").length;
if(selectedOptions == 5)
{
    ///ARRAY COM OS SELECIONADOS...
    var menu = $(this).val();
    ///DESABILITA AS OPÇÕES QUE NÃO FORAM MARCADAS...
    $("#columns-selected option:not(:selected)").attr('disabled','disabled');

    //ENVIA OS DADOS DO SELECT...
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: base_url+'fornecedor/menuPadrao/',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { menu: menu },
        success: function(data) 
        {
            if(!data.result == true){
                alert('Ocorreu um erro tente novamente!');
            }
        }
    }); 

}
else if(selectedOptions > 5)
{
    //SE MARCAR MAIS DE 5 OOÇÕES DE UMA VEZ (ex:USANDO A TECLA SHIFT), DESMARCA TUDO.
    $("#columns-selected").val([]);

} else if(selectedOptions < 5) {
    ///SE DESMARCAR UMA DAS OPÇÕES, LIBERA TODAS AS OPÇÕES DO SELECT DE NOVO;
    $("#columns-selected option:not(:selected)").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

})

Comment: @VisionDevelopment não tinha visto que você queria desabilitar apenas os que não foram marcados, se for isso, atualizei o código de acordo com a necessidade.
se te ajudar mano, por favor, marque a resposta como correta.vlw.